# R.layout.activity_main, NoClassDefFound error

Tags: java, android, r.java-file

I'm trying to compile Google Maps API v1 library replacement from this GitHub link [mapsv1](https://github.com/microg/android_frameworks_mapsv1) to include offline maps support. I modified MapActivity.java to look like this:

```
package com.google.android.maps;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import org.microg.annotation.OriginalApi;

import org.microg.mapsv1.osmdroid.R;
import org.osmdroid.api.IMapController;
import org.osmdroid.tileprovider.tilesource.XYTileSource;
import org.osmdroid.views.MapView;
import org.osmdroid.util.GeoPoint;

@OriginalApi
public class MapActivity extends Activity {

MapView map = null;

@OriginalApi
public MapActivity() {
    super();
}

@OriginalApi
protected boolean isLocationDisplayed() {
    return false;
}

@OriginalApi
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    return false;
}

@OriginalApi
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    map.setTileSource(new XYTileSource("OSMPublicTransport", 13, 16, 256, ".png", new String[]{}));
    map.setUseDataConnection(false); //optional, but a good way to prevent loading from the network and test your zip loading.
    IMapController mapController = map.getController();
    mapController.setZoom(15);
    GeoPoint startPoint = new GeoPoint(56.877879, 78.459979);
    mapController.setCenter(startPoint);
}

@OriginalApi
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

@OriginalApi
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
}

@OriginalApi
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}

@OriginalApi
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}
}
```

My activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<org.osmdroid.views.MapView
android:id="@+id/mapview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="org.microg.mapsv1.osmdroid">

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" />

<application />
</manifest>
```

build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
}
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

String getMyVersionName() {
def stdout = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
exec {
    commandLine 'git', 'describe', '--tags', '--always', '--dirty'
    standardOutput = stdout
}
return stdout.toString().trim()
}

repositories {
jcenter()
}

dependencies {
compile 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:5.1'
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    versionName getMyVersionName()
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
}
}

if (file('user.gradle').exists()) {
apply from: 'user.gradle'
}
```

However, I don't know how to compile the .jar library that I need to put in system/framework (I'm relatively new to this), so I run `./gradlew :mapsv1-flashable:assembleRelease` in the root folder to get a flashable zip.

Problem is that when I push the `com.google.android.maps.jar` onto the phone, the app that is using this library crashes as soon as it tries to open the map. The error says `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.microg.mapsv1.osmdroid.R$layout at com.google.android.maps.MapActivity.onCreate(MapActivity.java:54)`.

The 54th line reads `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

What is the problem? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/issues/375

Answer (score 0):

You have **NoClassDefFoundError** in **54th** line which does **setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);** because if you look in the **activity_main.xml** , you can note that you use **org.osmdroid.views.MapView** however **org.osmdroid.views.MapView** is not found.

To add jar in your project, you must create a directory named **libs** inside your **app** directory and put your jar files there. Then you must go to the **build.gradle** file and add your jar files in your module gradle dependencies like this:

```
dependencies{
   compile files('libs/your_jar_file.jar')
}
```

then when gradle will build your application, it will add you jar files.

Comment: I tried this now, but still the error is the same. I figured out that Gradle for some reason won't include R$layout file into the classes.dex. All other classes are included except this one. I renamed package name in AndroidManifest.xml to `com.google.android.maps`, and removed `import org.microg.mapsv1.osmdroid.R;`. What might you suggest?